# RGB cycle python

Tags: python, pygame, rgb

Does anyone know how to cycle through RGB values in python? Ex. R = 255, G = 255, B = 255

R -= 1 until 0 and then go back up and then make G go down and so on?

(This is for text colour in pygame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fairly easy shift to do - add some amount to each component of the colour, then ensure it is still within the legal bounds of the colour-value.  Here I've assumed 8-bit colour, so the valid range is 0-255.  Obviously if the code needed say 16 bit colour, the range would be bigger.

```
def shiftColour( colour, level_shift=-1 ):
    """ Return the colour with each component shifted (with boundary looping)"""
    red, green, blue = colour

    red += level_shift     # handle cycling in +/- for any level_shift
    if ( red < 0 ):
        red = 255
    elif ( red > 255 ):
        red = 0

    green += level_shift
    if ( green < 0 ):
        green = 255
    elif ( green > 255 ):
        green = 0

    blue += level_shift
    if ( blue < 0 ):
        blue = 255
    elif ( blue > 255 ):
        blue = 0

    return ( red, green, blue )   # re-combine, back into a colour
```

Shifting back down from the high-point is just a matter of remembering where the cycle is at.  You probably don't want to use the last say 50 values, since the colour would be mostly black.

```
### Main
colour = ( 255, 245, 235 )
delta  = 1
for i in range( 300 ):
    colour = shiftColour( colour, delta )
    print("R=%d, G=%d, B=%d" % ( colour[0], colour[1], colour[2] ) )
    if ( i % 50 == 0 ):
        delta *= -1
        print( "direction-change" )
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I never thought of shifting like that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max()` to get the largest number within the tuple and subtract each number until all are equal to or less than zero, like this:

```
RGB = (255,200,201)

red = RGB[0]
green = RGB[1]
blue = RGB[2]

step = -1

for i in range( max(RGB) * 2 + 2):

    print(
        "R:",red if red > 0 else 0,
        "G:",green if green > 0 else 0,
        "B:",blue if blue > 0 else 0
        )

    if all( map( lambda x: True if x < 0 else False, [red,green,blue] ) ):
        step = 1

    red += step
    green += step
    blue += step
```

As you can see, after all numbers are equal to or less than zero, the variable "step" is set to 1. This way we can make the numbers go back to their original values ​​by summing them.

Comment: This is raising TypeError: Invalid foreground RGBA argument. Thats in relation to font.render() in pygame

Comment: This error is probably being thrown because the value of one of the colors is negative or is being thrown by some other problem in your code. Before passing the color as an argument, check the tuple values.

Comment: yeah i did and right before the error was thrown r == 255 so im assuming it had just gone up once again to 256 being an invalid argument for 8 bit colour.

Comment: All good don't sweat it, I got it to work now using a little bit of everyones answers! Thanks for contributing always appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
r = 255
g = 255
b = 255
while(r>0):
    r-=1
    print("Red: %s" %r)
    if(r==0):
        while(g>0):
            g-=1
            print("Green: %s" %g)
            if(g==0):
                while(b>0):
                    b-=1
                    print("Blue: %s" %b)
```

I'm sure you can modify this abit to make it have a looping fade effect if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thing is with that though they all end up on 0 being black when the all the loops are over